# Nextcloud sync large files

Tags: php, apache, nextcloud

I've installed on linux Nextcloud server with apache+php. It works fine, but not sync large file > 2Gb. The error that I receive is:

```
Sabre\DAV\Exception: Error while copying file to target location (copied bytes: 0, expected filesize: -1 )
```

This is the all log:

```
[webdav] Fatal: Sabre\DAV\Exception: Error while copying file to target location (copied bytes: 0, expected filesize: -1 ) at <<closure>>

 0. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Connector/Sabre/Directory.php line 156
    OCA\DAV\Connector\Sabre\File->put(null)
 1. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Tree.php line 316
    OCA\DAV\Connector\Sabre\Directory->createFile("Manager.zip", null)
 2. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Tree.php line 130
    Sabre\DAV\Tree->copyNode(OCA\DAV\Upload\FutureFile {}, OCA\DAV\Files\FilesHome {}, "Manager.zip")
 3. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Tree.php line 161
    Sabre\DAV\Tree->copy("uploads/user/1599291976/.file", "files/user/Ma ... p")
 4. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/CorePlugin.php line 642
    Sabre\DAV\Tree->move("uploads/user/1599291976/.file", "files/user/Ma ... p")
 5. <<closure>>
    Sabre\DAV\CorePlugin->httpMove(Sabre\HTTP\Reque ... "}, Sabre\HTTP\Response {})
 6. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/event/lib/EventEmitterTrait.php line 105
    undefinedundefinedcall_user_func_array([Sabre\DAV\CorePlugin {},"httpMove"], [Sabre\HTTP\Requ ... }])
 7. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Server.php line 479
    Sabre\Event\EventEmitter->emit("method:MOVE", [Sabre\HTTP\Requ ... }])
 8. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Server.php line 254
    Sabre\DAV\Server->invokeMethod(Sabre\HTTP\Reque ... "}, Sabre\HTTP\Response {})
 9. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Server.php line 317
    Sabre\DAV\Server->exec()
10. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/apps/dav/appinfo/v2/remote.php line 35
    OCA\DAV\Server->exec()
11. /www/htdocs/nextcloud/remote.php line 163
    undefinedundefinedrequire_once("/www/htdocs/nex ... p")

MOVE /nextcloud/remote.php/dav/uploads/user/1599291976/.file
```

There is a way to resolve the problem?

My php.ini:

```
output_buffering = Off
upload_max_filesize = 16G
max_file_uploads = 20
post_max_size = 16G
max_input_time = 86400
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 86400
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

my httpd.conf

```
LimitRequestBody 2048000000000
SSLRenegBufferSize 2048000000000
```

my nextcloud/.htaccess

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
php_value output_buffering 0
php_value upload_max_filesize 16G
php_value post_max_size 16G
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

my nextcloud/.user.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=16G
post_max_size=16G
memory_limit=512M
mbstring.func_overload=0
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
default_charset='UTF-8'
output_buffering=0
```

the file on user/uploads/folder/ is present (i suppose)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon  10000000 Jan  5 16:38 00000000
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon  10000000 Jan  5 16:39 00000001
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon  10000000 Jan  5 16:39 00000002
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon  10000000 Jan  5 16:44 00000003
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:45 00000004
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:45 00000005
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:46 00000006
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:46 00000007
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:46 00000008
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:47 00000009
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:47 00000010
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:48 00000011
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:48 00000012
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:48 00000013
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:49 00000014
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:49 00000015
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:49 00000016
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:50 00000017
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:50 00000018
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:51 00000019
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:51 00000020
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:51 00000021
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:52 00000022
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:52 00000023
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:52 00000024
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:53 00000025
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:53 00000026
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:54 00000027
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:54 00000028
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:54 00000029
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:55 00000030
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:55 00000031
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 100000000 Jan  5 16:56 00000032
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon  69987987 Jan  5 16:56 00000033
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. I have NextCloud 17 in Docker, so it came with apache and php. I have mounted php.ini with the following settings: `upload_max_filesize = 204800M` and `post_max_size = 204800M` as a volume in my NC container, but still no luck.

Comment: I can also confirm that the same thing is happening in NextCloudPi

Comment: Still happing in NC 21.0 in 2021!

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a known php restriction on 32bit hosts and is filed as a bug here https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/16431

Comment: some feedback  from the question opener would be helpfull.  
I haven't tweek those PHP values in my setup (2MB default), and I can upload large files without any issue (>1GB)